Passing form inputted string to an entity's attribute
I have a medusajs website and backend. I am trying to add a metadata entity to the cart entity, when the customer is checking out their cart they are supposed to input a string which gets saved to the cart object which then gets created into an order and passed to my backend. Per their documentation it should be done like this. I am fairly new to web development and having trouble completing such an easy task.
Here is my attempt at doing this, it seems like the value in the Input component gives me an error because you can't set it as a key value pair, it has to be a string but my other attempts to fix this have not been so good either
"use client"

import { Heading, Text, clx } from "@medusajs/ui"
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react"
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"
import { Cart } from "@medusajs/medusa"
import Input from "@modules/common/components/input"
const CustomString = ({
cart,

}: {
 cart: Omit<Cart, "refundable_amount" | "refunded_total"> 

}) => {

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  //I have tried rewriting this in a couple different ways
    "cart.metadata": {"customString" : cart?.metadata || ""},
})

const searchParams = useSearchParams()
const isOpen = searchParams.get("step") === "review"

const previousStepsCompleted =
 cart.shipping_address &&
 cart.shipping_methods.length > 0 &&
 cart.payment_session

useEffect(() => {
    setFormData({
     "cart.metadata": {"customString" : cart?.metadata || ""},
  
    })
  }, [cart?.metadata])

const handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<
      HTMLInputElement | HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement
    >
  ) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
  }
return (
 <div>
  {isOpen && previousStepsCompleted && (
    <>
      <div className="flex items-start gap-x-1 w-full mb-6">

      <Input
      label="User Input"
      name="cart.metadata"
      maxLength={11}
      value= { cart?.metadata} //I get errors here
      onChange={handleChange}

          />

      </div>
    </>
  )}
</div>
)
}

export default CustomString

Any suggestions?
